# Flash AS3 Preloader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got a Flash AS3 animation that is completely coded in an .as file. The only thing on the timeline is the background image. All of the movieclips are Exported for ActionScript in frame1.

How would I go about adding a preloader into the .as file? I have tried a couple that I've found through Google but they don't seem to work as the .as file seems to be loaded instantly.

Any help greatly appreciated, S.

*Below is a stripped-down version of my as file:*

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.*; 

import gs.TweenLite;
import gs.easing.*;

public class rookbeareFarmClass extends MovieClip {             
    private var F1_Title:F1_Title_Keepitsimple;     

    public function main() {                    
        frame01();          
    }       

    // start frame 1 //
    private function frame01():void {           

        F1_Title = new F1_Title_Keepitsimple();
        addChild(F1_Title); 
        F1_Title.x=231;
        F1_Title.y=93;          
        F1_Title.alpha=0;               

        //Tween in
        TweenLite.to(F1_Title,2,{alpha:1,delay:0.5,ease:Cubic.easeOut,overwrite:0});                    

        //Tween out
        TweenLite.to(F1_Title,2,{alpha:0,delay:4.5,ease:Cubic.easeOut,overwrite:0});                    

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did you only test it on your own harddrive? That would explain why it would load instantly...

Comment: No - using Bandwidth Profiler and Simulate Download to check.

Comment: is the preloader for assets in your library? or is it for the container itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend compiling the SWF without a pre-loader - then create a separate "pre-loader" SWF that loads your main SWF. This will give you the most accurate loading information. Once the load is complete, you can call a public (init) function to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your movieclips and any heavy thing not needed for preloader have to be in frame 2, not 1. Preloader should occupy frame 1. Now your movie isn't probably loading instantly, it takes time to load fully and only then starts.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get them to export to frame2 when the mc's are Exported for ActionScript in frame1?

Comment: I'm not working with Flash, but I guess you need to uncheck that 'Export to first frame' option in symbol properties. Not sure where they will go, since you're not using timeline, maybe into frame two. I'd use SWiX ( http://www.swixkit.com ) to be sure.